# Cauchy's rigidity theorem

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Newbie here, I'm studying the proof of Cauchy's rigidity theorem, but couldn't find any good resources. I read the chapter about it Proofs from THE BOOK, but it's really brief and I was not able to fully understand it. Can someone recommend me some resources or places to search? The main part about creating a spherical polygon from a polyhedron and a sphere is pretty straight forward (once you know about the existence of a required vertex) (I will welcome arguments saying the opposite), but especially the Cauchy's arm lemma and the induction is not so easy to grasp.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the book *Geometric Folding Algorithms* by Erik Demaine and  Joesph O'Rourke?

Comment: Igor Pak's book "Lectures on Discrete and Polyhedral Geometry" available from https://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/book.htm may also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll take a look at both of them!

Comment: M. Berger, Geometry, vol. 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This paper (and its references) may help:

> O’Rourke, Joseph. "An extension of Cauchy’s arm lemma with application to curve development." In *Japanese Conference on Discrete and Computational Geometry*, pp. 280-291. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, 2000.
> [Springer link](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-47738-1_27).

[image: Fig1]

Comment: Thanks! I sent you a request for the paper on researchgate.net. I'll be really glad if you accept it.

Comment: Download from [this link](http://www.science.smith.edu/~jorourke/papers.php#35).

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.